# How do we know whether we will get a mono substituted or tri-substituted product during electrophilic aromatic substitution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, reactivity, phenols

For example consider the bromination of phenol we get the tri-substituted product (even though bromine is deactivating so I suppose it should deactivate the ring with each addition) while sulphonation essentially gives the mono-substituted product (even at high temperatures).[image]

Comment: The OH group is **strongly** activating, the bromines are only **slightly** deactivating.

Comment: @ron Okay.Then what about Nitration in phenol? It also gives tri-substituted product. NO2 is strongly deactivating.

Comment: A lot of it is experience, you pick it up as you go along.  That the nitration of phenol occurs so readily is a further reflection of just how activating the OH group is.

Comment: @ron Take a look at this link http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Textbook_Maps/Organic_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Bruice_6ed_"Organic_Chemistry"/16%3A_Reactions_of_Substituted_Benzenes/16.09_The_Synthesis_of_Trisubstituted_Benzenes      It's a good activator not excellent.

Comment: I see this, "In the case of the nitrogen and oxygen activating groups displayed in the top row of the previous diagram, electron donation by resonance dominates the inductive effect and these compounds show **exceptional reactivity** in electrophilic substitution reactions" (emphasis mine).  What do you see in the link?  You need to compare relative rates of reaction.

Comment: @ron Hmmm...Okay, you have a point. But then why do we not observe tri substitution in other products ,say sulphonation to phenol even though SO3H group is less deactivating then NO2. Or let's say Friedel crafts alkylation(CH3 being moderately activating) ?

Comment: Sulphonation is a little different because it is easily reversible, therefore product distribution is often thermodynamically controlled.  The weakly activating methyl group does undergo tri-nitration, but it requires forcing conditions.

Comment: @ron Is the exceptional reactivity of phenol strong enough to counter the effect of the three nitro groups that get substituted one by one ? Since nitro group is the most deactivating molecule for an aromatic ring .

Comment: @DelPate  Yes, the hydroxyl group activates the ring enough that 3 successive nitrations can occur.  As I mentioned in an earlier comment, even the weakly activating methyl group is strong enough to allow 3 successive nitrations under forcing conditions.

Answer (score 6):

It is like others have already noted that phenol is very strongly *ortho-para* directing, while bromine is only slightly deactivating (or sometimes slightly activating). It is so activating that you do not even need a Lewis acidic catalyst or elevated temperature to let the reaction go fast and in good yield. Moreover, if you want the mono substituted product you will actually need to cool the reaction down to < 5 °C and use the rather dangerously flammable solvent $\ce{CS_2}$, yielding 4-bromophenol in 85% yield (source: [Vogel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0582462363)). I assume the para product is formed due to the fact that there is no significant difference in electron density between ortho and para carbon atom while ortho is slightly sterically hindered.

Comment: Okay, so basically the answer is that we will get a tri-substituted product(if activating) unless- 1)Steric hindrance prohibits it    2)We use reaction conditions(like temperature,solvent) to favour some product. Would that be correct to say?

Answer (score 0):

In aqueous medium Phenol get converted to phenoxide ion which has more +M and it highly activates the ring and hence all the positions get occupied

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE!  If you haven't already, please take a minute to look over the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) and [tour page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand our guidelines and question policies. While your answer is not wrong we do strive for high quality on this site and would suggest you use more detail in this answer and future answers. Cheers!