# What will be the major product on chlorination of m-nitrophenol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nitro-compounds

I came across a question asking for the major product on chlorination of m-nitrophenol. In my opinion the deactivating nature of nitro group should control the regioselectivity, but I found out the answer to be 4-chloro-3-nitrophenol. But why is the activating nature of the hydroxyl group dominating over the deactivating nature of the nitro group?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> But why is the activating nature of hydroxyl group dominating over the deactivating nature of Nitro group?

This is the precise reason why [Picric acid](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picric_acid) is formed. ( [Check here](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/organicprops/phenol/ring.html) )
The activating nature of the $\ce{-OH}$ group is strong enough to counter the deactivating nature of the nitro groups.
Look at Ron's comment on the question over [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/25131/how-do-we-know-whether-we-will-get-a-mono-substituted-or-tri-substituted-product).
Even methyl group sustains deactivating nature of nitro group in the formation of [TNT](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinitrotoluene). So no wonder phenolic group, a better activator, dominates.

The phenolic group increases electron density on ortho para (making it o-p director) while nitro groups decrease e-density on the o-p positions (making it a meta director). When both these effects act simultaneously, the question is who wins and is the density on o-p carbons less than corresponding meta ones? (as that would decide where the electrophile will attack)

Resonace structures of the groups gives the solution.
In nitro group:

[image]

There are three charged atoms bonded together in the $\ce{-NO_2}$ molecule. This is less table than the positive charge bearing oxygen atom in phenolic group's resonance structure:

[image]

Hence phenolic group wins!!

Coming back to the given starting reactant:

[image]

So now we consider the dominating ortho-para effect of phenolic group over the meta-directing effect of nitro groups to get 4-chloro-3-nitrophenol:

[image]

Comment: Well, I had already understood that OH is dominating more an activating group over the deactivating nature of nitro but I still didnt get my answer "why". Anyways, thanks for coming up to help :-) My question was "why is it a better activator"

Comment: @DhrubaBanerjee I edited it to include the reason.

Comment: @DhrubaBanerjee This reasoning is a theoretical approach but experimental values confirm it .