# How does the solvent determine whether mono- or tribromination of phenol occurs?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, solvents, reaction-control, phenols

In phenol, the $-\ce{OH}$ group activates the benzene ring towards electrophilic substitution. But why is it that the electrophilic bromination of phenol gives trisubstitution (forming 2,4,6-tribromophenol) when aqueous bromine is used, but monosubstitution (either 2- or 4-bromophenol) when a $\ce{CCl4}$ solution of bromine is used? How does the solvent control the extent of bromination?

Related but does not explain completely: [How do we know whether we will get a mono substituted or tri-substituted product during electrophilic aromatic substitution?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/25131/how-do-we-know-whether-we-will-get-a-mono-substituted-or-tri-substituted-product)

Answer (score 5):

In aqueous medium, phenol is deprotonated to a certain extent, forming the phenoxide ion in which the *ortho* and *para* positions are even more activated than in phenol itself. Hence, trisubstitution occurs here.

$$\ce{PhOH + H2O <<=> PhO- + H3O+}$$

In an organic solvent, phenol is not deprotonated and monosubstitution tends to occur.

ron also pointed out in a comment that:

> 1. The concentration of $\ce{Br^+}$ is higher in water than in $\ce{CCl4}$ making the reaction faster in water.
> 2. The dielectric constant of water is much greater than that of $\ce{CCl4}$, so the former solvent will better stabilize the charged intermediate, again accelerating the reaction.